# Signed-in as admin on just part of the site

Tags: admin, user-access, admin-bar

I recently upgraded from WP 3.1 to 4.4.1. In the new setup, I am apparently seen as signed-in (as an admin) just on parts of the website (/blog/*) but not on other pages (that do not have the /blog/ prefix):

1. I only see the admin bar on http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/* posts, but not on pages (e.g. http://undocumentedmatlab.com/about/todo). On those pages, I see the non-logged-in new-comment section at the bottom of the page, which proves that I am not recognized as being signed-in.
2. I cannot see drafts of new posts - I can edit new posts but when I click the <Preview> button I get redirected to e.g. http://undocumentedmatlab.com/?p=6244 which gives a page-not-found error (because I'm apparently not logged in).

Both of these worked in my previous WP 3.1 installation of course.

I am always logged-in on my computer, I never logout. On some website pages WP recognizes that I'm logged-in, but for some unknown reason on other pages it does not.

How can I fix this so that WP knows that I'm signed-in?

**Edit**: I found out that by adding a call to `get_currentuserinfo();` in *header.php* the problem appears to be solved. I still do not know why it happened, but at least this is a working solution for anyone else who happens to have this problem.

Comment: You might want to make an answer to your question using the above edit then mark it answered.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that by adding a call to `get_currentuserinfo();` in *header.php* the problem appears to be solved. I still do not know why it happened, but at least this is a working solution for anyone else who happens to have this problem.

Note: Following @jgraup's suggestion above, I'm posting this as an answer. However, I am not marking this as accepted because I still do not know the original reason for the odd behavior, and maybe someone has a better solution.